# SQL case few row analysis

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I need some help with task below:
Table_A contains columns (ID, Name);
Table_B contains columns (ID, Category).

There are two possible category (Category_A, Category_B).

I'd like to get result table in format below:

```
|Name|Category_A|Category_B|
----------------------------
|Lilu|    NO    |   YES    |
```

But Table_B can contain two row for the same ID that we be meant e.g. "Lilu" belongs for both Catogory_A and Category_B as well. But in result I need one entry:

```
|Name|Category_A|Category_B|
----------------------------
|Lilu|   YES    |   YES    |
```

I prepare some query, but I miss grouping...

```
    select A.ID, --B.Category 
case when B.category = 'Category_A' then 'yes' else 'no' end Category_A,
case when B.category = 'Category_B' then 'yes' else 'no' end Category_B
from system.A_table A, B_table B;
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: You don't need Table A in your question. Table B is the only one necessary. Output 1 and 0 instead of 'yes'/'no'. and group your results with max(Category_A), max(Category_B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
select A.name, 
case when exist (Select b.Id from B_table b where b.id=A.id and b.category = 'Category_A') then 'yes' else 'no' end Category_A,
case when exist (Select b.Id from B_table b where b.id=A.id and b.category = 'Category_B') then 'yes' else 'no' end Category_B
from system.A_table A
```

Comment: That works, but it will be very heavy on the engine if the tables are large.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT T.Name,
 CASE WHEN MAX(T.Category_A)='' THEN 'no' ELSE MAX(T.Category_A) END as Category_A, 
CASE WHEN MAX(T.Category_B)='' THEN 'no' ELSE MAX(T.Category_B) END as Category_B
 ( 
select A.Name as Name, --B.Category 
 case when B.category = 'Category_A' then 'yes' else '' end Category_A,
 case when B.category = 'Category_B' then 'yes' else '' end Category_B
 from A_table A, B_table B WHERE A.ID=B.ID )
 T 
GROUP BY T.Name
```